# MS CRM: Show related record in subgrid based on records present in another subgrid (Relationship with three entity)

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online

I am new to MS CRM. I have below requirement:
I have Entity A B and C in MS CRM 2016.

"Entity A" can have multiple "Entity B" records which are currently being displayed on "Entity A" form using 1 to N relationship.
"Entity C" can have multiple "Entity A" records.I am able to display associated "Entity A" records on "Entity C" form using 1 to N relationship.
On "Entity C" form, I want to display "Entity B" records  associated with all of the "Entity A" which are associated with "Entity C". How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create 1:N relationship between Entity C and Entity B and follow one of the below steps. Then create a subgrid on Entity C which list down the related Entity B records.

1. Develop a plugin on Create & Update of Entity B to set the Entity C lookup (grand parent) based on the value selected in Entity A lookup (parent) in Entity B.
2. Create a field mapping in Entity B:

   - Source Entity: Entity A
   - Source Field: Entity C lookup in Entity A
   - Target Entity: Entity B
   - Target Field: Entity C lookup in Entity B

**C** --*1:N*--> **A** --*1:N*--> **B**

**C** --*1:N*--> **B**

[Edited:] Below image shows what I explained above, and which is achieved using step #2.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to create a 1 to Many relationship between Entity C and B and a time of grid load you have to update the fecth xml of grid to filter the records to display only which are associated with entity A.